# Single Line Address in Postcode Anywhere?

Tags: testing, postal-code

I am trying to implement Postcode Anywhere into my site but can't seem to get the whole address into one text field. Has anyone used this software before and if so how can you do it?? It only puts one line in the text field such as just the postcode or just the first address line but I want the entire address in one line.

I have looked it up at http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/address-validation/try-it-now/ and also contact them but still can't figure out how to do it!

The page I am trying to put it on is www.ultimatelockingvengeance.co.uk

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Christie

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the on-screen mapping tool, once you have selected the field to be mapped under "your fields", you want to select the "label" option under "our fields" as you can see here - http://www.postcodeanywhere.com/support/articles/article/getting-started-with-captureplus

Save the changes and you should be done!